# Ubuntu 12.10 graphics or booting issue

Tags: 12.04, unity, 12.10, boot, intel-graphics

Merry Christmas everyone.

Yesterday I upgraded Ubuntu from 12.04 to 12.10. I have an Intel integrated graphic card. I know it's not compatible with the new version. Ubuntu warned me about it, but I upgraded Ubuntu anyway.

My main idea is to disable Unity 3D after the upgrade, or use Cinnamon, but now I'm facing problems... I see the boot loader, I click Ubuntu and then all I see is a purple screen, just that. I don't see the loading screen or the login screen, just a purple screen. What to do? Can I fix it without removing 12.10 and reinstalling 12.04?

Comment: When you get the Grub menu press `e` find the line containing `quiet splash` and add `nomodeset` after a space. Might permit you to boot properly.

Comment: @ToDo it's not a `nomodeset` problem, i had that problem before, when i was installing ubuntu 12.04 and i solved it by reading [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132) so i already added `nomodeset`

Comment: if this issue isn't fixed by wednesday, i'm gonna have to uninstall ubuntu and reinstall it or maybe move back to my favorite os linux mint, the thing is i have a big python project from the french embassy in my country, and we all know that i can't use virtualenv on windows + windows sucks for programmers and python guys, so if u read this question thursday, u don't have to answer, because i won't have ubuntu 12.10 by then, i am racing against the clock, the faster you can solve it, it will be better.

Comment: i even appreciate it if u tell me that i have to uninstall it and I'll do it now rather than wasting time

Comment: Can you switch to one of the virtual terminals with ctrl-alt-F2 ?

Comment: @ubfan1 if i can, what's your solution?

Comment: Do a sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback or some other desktop.  Then when you get the login screen, click on the little gear by your username and select gnome.

Comment: @ubfan1 nome-session-fallback is already installed on my pc, i installed it just before i upgraded just in case the upgrade didn't work, and i don't even get to a login screen as i said, i select ubuntu from the grub menu, and all i see is a purple screen, it freezes or something, so i can't use nome-session-fallback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar problem with install in Oracle VirtualBox after configuring boot and swap partition as well. I also installed metacity, kernal headers (Ubuntu 12.10), manually downloaded VB additions, etc. Then I found to kill process with gnome-session provided a GUI login screen. Then I select Classic Gnome. To get the panel again I also had to kill process with gnome-panel - also from Ctrl-Alt-Fx (x from 1 to 6) as root. Maybe this helps somebody a bit further along. (836 GB RAM, 128 MB Video ram, 8GB hdd dynamic). (No problem on vmplayer 5.1 - I hope) Server is Windows 7 on HP Probook.